# Flash game on Steam

Tags: flash, porting, steam

I have almost completed a game written in flash/as3 using flixel.
How can I sell it through steam ?

A few years back, (I was a full-time flash game dev back then..) there were 2 choices:

- Use Adobe Air to make the game downloadable.
- Use 3rd party flash wrappers like [Zink](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/), that are bit more poewrfull, but for a price.

And of course, there's the option to write it from scratch in some other language..

I wonder, since I've been hidden in cave these years, and I'm not really up-to-date with the flash-game market (I know it's dying..), what are my options to publish and monetize my as3 game to the desktop market ?

Feel free to drop any idea, even if it's not directly solving my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also try [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) and cross compile it as an executable. There is a [AS3 converter](http://haxe.org/doc/flash/usingas3classes) and using [OpenFL](http://www.openfl.org/) you can keep using the flash API. [fixel](https://github.com/HaxeFlixel/flixel) is ported as well. You still might end up in some troubles here and there but the community is active and helpful and a good source to get some quick help is their [IRC Channel](http://haxe.org/com/meeting/irc?lang=en) and [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/haxelang).

Comment: well, thats something new, thanx, I'll look into it

Comment: I obviously don't have enough time to try porting a flash game into Haxe, but I think this might be the best option so far. The ability to publish to any platform  sounds really sweet. Additionally, I can see that lots of experienced as3 veterans are switching to haxe/openFL, so I expect to see a live community, and familiar APIs and dev tools. Thank you for pointing me out there. I'll will just for a while, before accepting your answer

Comment: using Adobe AIR also gives you opportunity to target any platforms (windows/macOS/iOS/android) and it would probably need almost no recoding at all.

Comment: true, and I might actually prefer trying air, given that my game is almost finished. I'm mentioning Air in my question too. But I was using air some years ago and i remember it produced limited and unreliable desktop applications. Now that Adobe is killing flash, I don't think it got better

Answer (score 2):

Steam is possible, as long as the game is packaged into an executable.
Quality of course has to be pretty strong to get there.

Steam Greenlight : http://steamcommunity.com/greenlight/faq/

Online platforms : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026503/popular-flash-games-on-stream

Comment: FYI: Your link to "Flash Games on Steam" gives 0 results ;)

Comment: For me it gives five results.

Comment: Thank you for the info. To be honest, I've done my googling, and I knew about greenlight. If I got it right, greenlight is mandatory if you're going to post something on Steam anyway... The S.O. thread about Flash Games on Steam is outdated (mochigames is closed). The flash games tag on steam gives me 5 results indeed, but I'm not sure how would that help me.

Comment: Removed the steam link, it was unreliable

Answer (score 1):

Just to round out ScrambleRK's answer, there is a more recent, OpenFl compliant version of as3hx available. You can find it here:
https://github.com/openfl/as3hx

As3hx is essentially an command-line tool, but it's fairly simple to use. I recently ported an API using the tool. There was some post-editing that needed to be done on the generated hx files, but for the most part it was minimal (most issues had to do dynamic typing).

There is also a haxe port of flixel available called HaxeFlixel. You can check it out here:
https://github.com/HaxeFlixel/flixel

Comment: Yes, porting to haxeFlixel is probalbly the best thing to do in my case. Unfortunately, as3hx didn't help much, so I'm still porting the wholke as3 code to hx manually.